# Scheduled Backup of Files / SMS / Contacts to Email

Tags: backup

Currently I am using [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&hl=en) to regularly backup my SMS to Gmail daily. It works perfectly.

Now I am looking for a similar software that backs up files (on folders I select from SDcard) as well as my contacts regularly (daily/weekly for example).

Does anyone know apps that can do this? Preferably no root required but if I have to I might as well just root.

Comment: Backing up contacts? Doesn't Google take care of that already? Also do you have a preference about where you want your files?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik I use another Google account for my phone. The reason is I do not want a thief to access to my Google account in case it gets stolen/lost. Due to this, I kinda treat my phone contacts like an old school phone, totally separate list. About the files, I like to choose predefined folders that will be backedup regularly via email or dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

If root is an option, the ultimate answer would be [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup). Scheduled backup of everything, support for Dropbox and more.

As for folders, I'd say [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) is certainly worth a try. Support for many cloud services, as well as your own servers via FTP and more.